# Generating an artificial spatially correlated variable in R

Tags: r, sf, autocorrelation

I have an `sf` multipolygon dataframe object and would like to generate a spatially correlated variable for a given value of Moran's I.

I was trying to understand relevance of kriging functions here in `gstat` but they seem to require dependent and independent variables. And moreover, as I understand kriging is non-parametric (CMIIW). Also st_sample()

Basically, I wish to generate a random spatially autocorrelated field as in for example, we can generate an error term from a random normal distribution (given mean and variance).

Comment: I don't think this is generally possible for a given connectivity or weights matrix between areas. Consider three areas, A, B, and C, where each is connected to the other two. I don't think you can generate three values to produce a Moran I of -1. I'm not sure what the lower limit would be, but its a function of the weights matrix. If I can work this through mathematically I may post a full answer later.

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman. Basically my objective is to compare my regression estimates in the presence/absence of SAC (for which I wanted to generate those errors). Alternatively, considering an extension of your example of 3 areas A, B and C (which are divided into subregions which are my spatial units of observations), is there a way to generate a variable whose values are correlated within A, B and C but independent across the 3 areas? I think one may need to start with a mutivariate normal distribution? And if yes, how should one go about accounting for the weights matrix?

Comment: I still don't understand. The things that go into a Moran's I are the values at each location, and the matrix giving the weight between any two locations, which is often a binary matrix with a 1 for adjacent cells. Which of these have you got to play with in order to try and get a given Moran's I (between -1 and 1)?

Comment: @Spacedman. Many thanks for your comment.I should have been more clear. Let us consider a simple situation where I have 100 obs. units (rows in my sf dataframe). I know that the Id variable (according to which they are arranged) has a spatial pattern, so that ID from 1 to 50 are in the north and 51-100 are southern units.  Suppose I generate a variable such that the values are correlated within north and south (bt indt btwn north & south), I should get a spatially correlated variable (with a higher abs Moran's I - value not known ex-ante, can find out later from ```spdep::moran.test```)?

Comment: Can you edit your Q to clarify all this, and maybe add some code to set the situation up? It sounds like your example is a 10x10 grid with 4-adjacent cells. Show the Moran I for when all the northern cells have value 1 and the southern cells have value 0, and for when the cells alternate 0/1 - that gives the possible range of I given that weight matrix and set of values. For your task, do you allow change of weight matrix and/or values? Put all this into an edit of the question.